# How to configure HP Smart Array P822 controller with single SAS HDD

Tags: hp-smart-array, sas

I have SAS Seagate Exos HDD and HP P822 Smart Array controller with 2GB cache with battery backup.

I don't want to create any arrays, this is supposed to be single storage HDD in my workstation. All important stuff I back up regularly so I don't need RAID for that.

How to properly configure P822 to avoid troubles in future?

What I did.

I have created single disc RAID 0 with this SAS HDD and then it started to appear in Windows' Disk Management tool, then I partitioned it and formatted. Is that correct configuration?

Any suggestions how to set up cache or RAID 0 settings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a correct configuration.